# Mouse exit event from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I am using this multiselect dropdown for angularjs
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

If you check the demo and select dropdown, a list of options appears. Users selects the options and clicks outside the dropdown list, the dropdown list closes.

At this instant, I want to fire a function. Can anyone please let me know how to get this mouse exit event and how to run a function in Angularjs?

Comment: use `ng-mouseleave` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

Comment: Or `ng-blur` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the component you are using does not send any event when it closes. You can create a pull request and add it [here](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js#L165), i.e.:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.open = false;
    $scope.externalEvents.onClose();
});
```

Then, you could use it as any other event as described in the docs.